# Is conduction band discrete or continuous?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, discrete

My question is very simple. I just want to know that is conduction band discrete or continuous?

Comment: At what temperature and pressure?  Doppler broadening and [pressure broadening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_broadening) (of the [electron gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_electron_model#Properties_of_an_electron_gas)) smear a discrete transition over a range of energies.  At very low temperatures and pressures, this doesn't matter so much.  In very thin objects, [inhomogeneous broadening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_line#Inhomogeneous_broadening) also occurs.  (Don't get too hung up on natural broadening -- we're talking ground states here.)

Comment: In a perfect crystal it is effectively continuous.  Defects, impurities, crystal boundaries, or amorphous regions introduce discontinuities.

Comment: From far enough away, everything looks continuous. Close enough to it, everything looks discrete. The answer is **yes**.

Answer (score 9):

> [A useful way to visualize](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solids/band.html) the difference between conductors, insulators and semiconductors is to plot the available energies for electrons in the materials. Instead of having discrete energies as in the case of free atoms, the available energy states form bands.

[image]

Read on the link.

You ask:

> My question is very simple. I just want to know that is conduction band discrete or continuous

The band theory  is a quantum mechanical  model,   such that the difference between energy levels in the band  is very small, mathematically discrete but experimentally continuous. That is why it is called a "band".

Comment: `+1` but is "continuous" the answer? I see, for a finite size crystal the discrete nature of the conduction band is related to boundary conditions? Also Isn't temperature the deciding factor between whether a pure crystal is an insulator or a semiconductor at least electrically? Pure silicon at 0.1 Kelvin is probably an insulator, diamond at 4,000 Kelvin might be a semiconductor?

Comment: @uhoh sure, if one wants real solutions to the multidimensional potential probem that a lattice is .The band theory is a model based on quantum mechanics, but has all these as parameters in its sloutions.

Answer (score 6):

As other have noted, it's discrete but with fine enough spacing to treat as continuous.

However I disagree that quantum mechanics is the reason. You see the exact same thing in a [classical 1-D chain of masses connected by springs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon#One-dimensional_lattice).

The allowed wave vectors $\vec{k}$ in the bands are [reciprocal lattice vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_lattice), and the number of reciprocal lattice vectors is equal to the number of real-space (aka direct) lattice vectors. That in turn is equal to the number of atoms. So, if you have an infinite number of atoms in your lattice, then there are an infinite number of reciprocal lattice vectors, and your band is continuous. (I guess it's countably infinite which is a little different that continuous, but let's not go there.)

Real materials have a finite number of atoms, so the bands are, strictly speaking, not continuous. However, most crystals that people deal with are large enough that the number of atoms is huge --- effectively infinite.

Comment: The classical normal modes have a discrete spectrum of frequencies, but these do not correspond to their energies in a classical description. The connection to discrete energy (as opposed to frequency) is very much a quantum not a classical aspect of the physics here.

Comment: This is true, but it's not answering the question that was asked.

Comment: So the mathematical answer is "discrete" but even for a small, pure, perfectly polished crystal there is phonon scattering at finite temperature, so while each state is discrete we can excite between them because each has a finite lifetime therefore finite width?

Comment: Yes, I think that's a fair thing to say.

Answer (score 4):

As this model is itself associated with quantum model, so it seems obvious that energy levels occur in steps or we can say that they are discrete but experimental analysis says that they are continuous and it's intuitive that they are too close that's why we call them a band i.e  a band of too close energy levels.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the answers given so far:

In any finite system, the energy levels are discrete, and the number of energy levels is proportional to the number of atoms in your system.

So if you have a particle only a few atoms across, your energy levels are noticeably distinct, even within the same band. But for a macroscopic crystal, the number of levels is in the region of Avogadro's number (about $10^{23}$), so your band will be effectively continuous. Even theoretically, one describes such macroscopic systems by considering the limit of an infinite crystal, so the bands become continuous.

A related phenomenon mentioned in the comments is energy broadening at finite temperatures. This does not change the quantum mechanical energy levels, but prevents you from seeing them as discrete lines in an absorption/emission spectra.